# Janrain - Remove Default Sign In As

Tags: facebook, janrain

I have Janrain Engage for a site with three providers (Facebook, Google, Yahoo)

If a users authenticates say via Facebook on my site and then comes back to my site, instead of showing the three login options it shows only Facebook Icon and Sign In As NAME. To get to the screen with the three options you have to press "Switch Accounts".

Is there anyway for JanRain not to do this? Not to only show the login option you previously used, but instead show all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your block of widget settings (assuming you're using the newer widget):

> janrain.settings.noReturnExperience = true;